# How do you default default props for an optional child property of a required prop in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I have a required object, but not all of it's children are required.

For example, this is what I'm trying to do:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const propTypes = {
  bike: PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    color: PropTypes.string
  }).isRequired
}
const defaultProps = {
  bike: {
    color: 'red'
  }
}
```

In this example, I'm trying to say that the bike object is required with an id, but the color is not required and will be red by default.

With my ESLint rules (AirBnb's default set for the most part), I get the following error:

> defaultProp "bike" defined for isRequired propType.
>   (react/default-props-match-prop-types)

Any ideas on how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

This makes no sense to do anyway. Default props does a shallow merge which means that when you supply the bike prop it will overwrite the default prop you set.

Also, are you actually setting the default props and prop types on the component?

Comment: If the props you set don't include a color, is there a way to default it to red?

Comment: And yes, I'm setting the propTypes and defaultProps to the component, but didn't include that or the actual component code because its not really relevant here.

Comment: A few options: split the prop up so it's flat and not nested or manually set default color in the constructor or componentWillMount or use recompose [`flattenProp`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#flattenprop) to flatten the nested prop, you can then set the defaults for color without it being nested